# Three.js - Skybox showing black

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem adding a skybox to a simple scene in Three.js !

The code i use for the skybox is:

```
    var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1500, 1500, 1500 ), shaderMaterial );
        sceneCube.add( skyBox );
```

The shaderMaterial is defined as followed:

```
shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "cube" ];
shader.uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = textureCube;

var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
    uniforms: shader.uniforms,
    depthWrite: false,
    side: THREE.BackSide

} );
```

I just want to display some simple Images as Skybox so i use this to load the Images:

```
     var path = "Desert-";
            var format = '.png';
            var urls = [
                path + 'LEFT' + format, path + 'RIGHT' + format,
                path + 'TOP' + format, path + 'BOT' + format,
                path + 'FRONT' + format, path + 'BACK' + format
            ];
            textureCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls );
```

Running my code does not throw any errors in the web-console. As basic scene i use http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube.

I really tried to find an answer in the internet, but i can not find anything i am doing wrong here.

Thank you for your help!

Here the full code i use (I post this cause i really tried to apply all solutions to it, which were posted here).

```
<script>

        var camera, scene, renderer, cameraCube, sceneCube;
        var mesh, shader;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
            camera.position.z = 400;
            cameraCube = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );


            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            sceneCube = new THREE.Scene();


            var path = "textures/Desert-";
            var format = '.png';
            var urls = [
                path + 'LEFT' + format, path + 'RIGHT' + format,
                path + 'TOP' + format, path + 'BOTTOM' + format,
                path + 'FRONT' + format, path + 'BACK' + format
            ];
            console.log(urls);
            textureCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls );

            // Skybox

            shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "cube" ];
            shader.uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = textureCube;

            var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

                fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
                vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
                uniforms: shader.uniforms,
                depthWrite: false,
                side: THREE.BackSide

            } );


            var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1500, 1500, 1500 ), shaderMaterial );
            sceneCube.add( skyBox );

            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( urls[3] );

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( mesh );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();


            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render( sceneCube, cameraCube );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

Comment: The geometry cube demo has a camera far parameter of 1000. Your cube is 1500. Be sure the camera far is correct.

Comment: I use THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 ); So i guess my cube should be seen. That is why i asked my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using multiple render passes like so:

```
renderer.render( sceneCube, cameraCube );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

you will need to set

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
```

to prevent the second render pass from clearing the first one.

three.js r.76

Comment: Thank you, this really seems to be the Solution for my Problem! Thank you very much!